# "TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not tuple" what to do? (pygame starter)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm starting to learn pygame and python and recently I got this error message:

> "TypeError: must be pygame.Surface, not tuple"

This is the code part that giving me the error:

```
# circles basic setup 
circle = screen, white
radius = 5.5
surface = 10, 10
pygame.draw.circle(surface, white, (183, 218), 0, 5)
```

the full code:

```
import pygame, time

from pygame import mixer, surface

pygame.init()

# define colors
red = (255, 255, 255)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# define size's
widthScreen, heightScreen = 368, 406

# define sounds
movingSound = "Pacman Waka Waka.mp3"

# setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((widthScreen, heightScreen))
pygame.display.set_caption("PacMan Goes")
screen.fill(white)


pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (0, 0, widthScreen, heightScreen), 5)
pac = pygame.image.load("pacman.png")
pac = pygame.transform.scale(pac, (22, 22))
pac_rect = pac.get_rect()
pac_rect.move_ip(173, 218)
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('pacManSong.mp3')
mixer.music.play()

# speed in pixels per frame
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
# define Background
bg = pygame.image.load("pacmanBackground.jpg").convert()
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (widthScreen, heightScreen))
openScreen = pygame.image.load("Pac-Man_Logo.PNG")

# circles basic setup
position = (183, 218)
radius = 5  # expected integer
border_size = 5

pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, position, radius, border_size)

time.sleep(4)

game_on = True
#   -------------- Main Program Loop --------------   #
while game_on:
# --- Event Processing --- #
screen.fill(white)
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    game_on = False
    # user pressed down on a key
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    # figure out if that was an arrow key, if so
    # adjust speed.
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        pac = pygame.image.load("pacmanLeft.png")
        pac = pygame.transform.scale(pac, (20, 20))
        mixer.music.load('Pacman Waka Waka.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        x_speed = -3
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        mixer.music.load(movingSound)
        mixer.music.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pac = pygame.image.load("pacman.png")
        pac = pygame.transform.scale(pac, (20, 20))
        x_speed = 3
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        mixer.music.load(movingSound)
        mixer.music.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pac = pygame.image.load("Up.png")
        pac = pygame.transform.scale(pac, (20, 20))
        y_speed = -3
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        pac = pygame.image.load("Down.png")
        pac = pygame.transform.scale(pac, (20, 22))
        mixer.music.load(movingSound)
        mixer.music.play()
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        y_speed = 3
    # user let up on a key
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    #if it is an arrow key reset vector back to 0
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_speed = 0
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        y_speed = 0
if pac_rect.right >= widthScreen or pac_rect.right <= 0 and pac_rect.left >= widthScreen or pac_rect.left <= 0:
    x_speed *= -1

if pac_rect.bottom >= heightScreen or pac_rect.bottom <= 0 and pac_rect.top >= heightScreen or pac_rect.top <= 0:
    y_speed *= -1
pac_rect = pac_rect.move(x_speed, y_speed)
screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
screen.blit(pac, pac_rect)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Comment: BTW: you draw white circle on white background so you can't see it :)

Comment: pygame doesn't send directly on monitor but to buffer and you have to use `pygame. display.flip()` or `pygame. display.update()` to send buffer on monitor. You doesn't use `pygame. display.update()` before `time.sleep(4)` so it doesn't send circle on monitor. After `time.sleep(4)` you use `pygame. display.update()` but first you use `screen.fill(white)` so it removes circle from buffer.

Comment: The error message is pretty self-descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

[pygame.draw.circle()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) expects [pygame.Surface()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object as first argument but you use tuple `10, 10`. You can use `screen` to draw in window.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

position = (183, 218)
radius = 5  # expected integer
border_size = 5

pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, position , radius, border_size)
```

---

**EDIT:** full working example

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

#empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

#empty

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# - objects -

# use center of screen as circle center
circle_position = screen_rect.center

circle_radius_1 = 5  # expected integer
circle_radius_2 = 100  # expected integer

circle_border_size = 5

# - mainloop --

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # - updates (without draws) -

    circle_radius_1 += 1
    if circle_radius_1 > WIDTH/2:
        circle_radius_1 = 5

    circle_radius_2 += 1
    if circle_radius_2 > WIDTH/2:
        circle_radius_2 = 5    

    # - draws (without updates) -

    # clear buffer (surface `screen`)
    screen.fill(BLACK) 
    # draw circle on buffer (surface `screen`)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, circle_position , circle_radius_1, circle_border_size)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, circle_position , circle_radius_2, circle_border_size)
    # send buffer (surface `screen`) on monitor
    pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

---

**EDIT:** your code with modifications. I tested it without music.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

WIDHT_SCREEN = 368
HEIGHT_SCREEN = 406

FPS = 30

MOVING_SOUND = "Pacman Waka Waka.mp3"

# --- classe --- (CamelCase names)

# class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
#    pass

# class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
#    pass

# class YellowEnemy(Enemy):
#    pass

# --- main --- (lower_case  names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDHT_SCREEN, HEIGHT_SCREEN))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("PacMan Goes")

# - music - 

pygame.mixer.music.load('pacManSong.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# - objects -

# - objects - player -

x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

pac_left = pygame.image.load("pacmanLeft.png")
pac_left = pygame.transform.scale(pac_left, (20, 20))

pac_right = pygame.image.load("pacman.png")
pac_right = pygame.transform.scale(pac_right, (20, 20))

pac_up = pygame.image.load("Up.png")
pac_up = pygame.transform.scale(pac_up, (20, 20))

pac_down = pygame.image.load("Down.png")
pac_down = pygame.transform.scale(pac_down, (20, 20))

pac = pac_right
pac_rect = pac.get_rect(x=173, y=218)

# - objects - background -

bg = pygame.image.load("pacmanBackground.jpg").convert()
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (WIDHT_SCREEN, HEIGHT_SCREEN))
open_screen = pygame.image.load("Pac-Man_Logo.PNG")

# - objects - circles -

position = (183, 218)
radius = 5  # expected integer
border_size = 5

# - clock - FPS -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# --- first scene ---

# - draws -

screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, screen_rect, 5)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, position, radius, border_size)
pygame.display.update()

# - mainloop - "sleep" but still react on ESC press

current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
end_time = current_time + 4000 # 4000ms = 4s

running = True

while running and end_time > current_time:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False

    # --- constants speed on fast and slow computer

    clock.tick(FPS)

    # --- updates ---

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# --- second scene - game ---

# - mainloop -

game_on = True

while game_on:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_on = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pac = pac_left
                pygame.mixer.music.load(moving_sound)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
                x_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pac = pac_right
                pygame.mixer.music.load(moving_sound)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
                x_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pac = pac_up
                pygame.mixer.music.load(moving_sound)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
                y_speed = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pac = pac_down
                pygame.mixer.music.load(moving_sound)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
                y_speed = 3
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN):
                y_speed = 0

    # --- updates ---

    if pac_rect.left <= screen_rect.left or pac_rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
        x_speed *= -1

    if pac_rect.top <= screen_rect.top or pac_rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
        y_speed *= -1

    pac_rect.move_ip(x_speed, y_speed)

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(pac, pac_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- constants speed on fast and slow computer

    clock.tick(FPS)

# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: now it isnt giving the error message but it isnt showing it on the screen

Comment: did you use `pygame.display.update()` ? Did you draw on `screen` or any other surface which you have to `blit()` on `screen` ?

Comment: try to check my code maybe you''l find the answer there why it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
circle = screen, white
radius = 5.5
surface = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
pygame.draw.circle(surface, white, (183, 218), 0, 5)
```

(http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: try to check my code maybe you''l find the answer there why it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to initialize pygame. This is my working example, feel free to ask me further question!

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World')

radius = 5 #must be integer
WHITE = (255,255,255)
circle = pygame.draw.circle(surface,WHITE,(50,50),radius)


while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: try to check my code maybe you''l find the answer there why it isnt working